# How to take column of integers and assign string value based on range

Tags: splunk

I am a splunk novice and looking to take a column of int values and have them display as a string based on the range they fall in.

```
I.e.
Ints from 1-100 should display: Low 
Ints from 101-200 should display: Medium 
Ints from 201-300 should display: High
```

I believe I can use an eval statement to accomplish this, but am not sure where to go from there. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to make it into a case statement:

```
| eval "new_column" = case (
    variable_evaluating >= 1 AND variable_evaluating <= 100, "Low",
    variable_evaluating >= 101 AND variable_evaluating <= 200, "Medium", 
    variable_evaluating >= 201, "High")
```